# Display country flags with clickable links

Tags: plugin-polylang

I want to trigger something like this:

Display a drop-down menu where I can have a country's flag and name and when i click one of them, it redirects me to a certain link.

The thing is that i have a website that writes in 3 languages; english, French & kinyarwanda.

Every language is hosted on a particular sub domain, and I want to link them to them using that method since thale auto tlanslators can't read kinyarwanda.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The redirecting "drop-down" (`select` element) part of your question can be answered by looking at this fiddle that someone made for a different question:
https://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/2f9wvyqm/

As far as getting the flags to appear in the `option` elements of the `select` element, the only way to get it to work cross-browser (that I know of), would be to find some kind of fancy font-icons to use.
Otherwise, for best compatibility, I would suggest faking a select element with some jQuery or a jQuery Library.

The topic of images in `option` elements, and many of the available options, is covered thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list) - including one example of a library with a [flag-bearing language selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41417326/7656220).